# How to use Linq to Group By individual items in a Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I'm trying to find the most popular `Tags` that are used for a `BlogPost`.

eg.

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

So I tried:

```
var tags = (from p in BlogPosts()
        group bp by bp.Tags into g
        select new {Tag = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
    .Take(number);
```

but this doesn't compile. Error is:
`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<{Tag: System.IEnumerable<string>, Count: int}>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>'.`

See how it's a list of strings? I was hoping to look through each tag in every blog post, and count the most popular ones.

Comment: The error you're getting comes from outside the code you posted. Could you show the code where the error is reported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can group on a `IEnumerable<string>`, try this:

```
var tags = (from t in BlogPosts.SelectMany(p => p.Tags)
        group t by t into g
        select new {Tag = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
    .Take(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

SelectMany is the key here.

```
  var tags = posts
     .SelectMany (p => p.Tags)
     .GroupBy (t => t).Select(t => new {Tag = t.First (), Count=t.Count ()})
     .OrderBy(tc => tc.Count)
     .Select(tc => tc.Tag)
     .Take (15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to group on singular tag names, not on whole lists of tags, which is what you are currently doing. Try this:

```
var tags =
    (from p in posts
    from tag in p.Tags
    group tag by tag into g
    select new {Tag = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Count)
.Take(number);
```

Though this should do what you are asking for, it won't fix the compile error you're getting. That's somewhere else.